# folderbrowserdialog selected path

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog

i'm using 'folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath' to have a path to chosen folder. How can i see the names of another folders in folder which is selected?

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(subDir.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`Directory.GetDirectories` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29kt2zfk.aspx) namespace contains a lot of tools for this. The [`Directory.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) you can use to get al subfolders.

For example:

```
 var folder = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
 var subFolders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folder);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **FolderBrowserDialog** component is displayed at run time using the **ShowDialog** method. Set the **RootFolder** property to determine the top-most folder and any subfolders that will appear within the tree view of the dialog box. Once the dialog box has been shown, you can use the **SelectedPath** property to get the path of the folder that was selected

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories` method.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories(v=vs.71).aspx